# How would I setup bamboo unit testing that runs both karma and jest

Tags: jestjs, karma-runner, bamboo

I have been trying to set up server-side testing for my application but have run into an issue with bamboo recognizing more than one test type. In the past, it worked just fine using only karma as the unit test, but I need to add server-side testing which works much better with jest.

The main problem I am running into is that when both are run as shown below the coverage report is only created for the karma(unit) tests.

```
test-unit=npm run test:unit && npm run test:server
```

I have also tried running jest under bamboos test-e2e and test-contract-test but when I do this nothing is reported. So is there a way to set up server-side testing separately in the .bamboorc file

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an answer!
In the .bamboorc file move the test-unit = npm run test:unit to the end of the file and for the first test use

```
test-contract-consumer=npm run test:server -- --collect-coverage
```

This should then collect the coverage for the server tests in bamboo under the contract tests consumer artifacts, and the karma unit test should still show up under the unit test coverage artifacts.